# How to usage Obx() with getx in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, get, flutter-getx

On my UI screen, I have 2 textfields in a column. If textFormFieldEntr is empty, hide textFormFiel. If there is a value in the textFormFieldEntr, let the other textfield be visible. After I set the bool active variable to false in the Controller class, I checked the value in the textFormFieldEntr in the showText class. I'm wrong using obx on the UI screen. The textfields are listed in the _formTextField method. Can you answer by explaining the correct obx usage on the code I shared?

```
class WordController extends GetxController {
  TextEditingController controllerInput1 = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController controllerInput2 = TextEditingController();
  bool active = false.obs();

  final translator = GoogleTranslator();
  RxList data = [].obs;

  @override
  void onInit() {
    getir();
    super.onInit();
  }

  void showText() {
    if (!controllerInput1.text.isEmpty) {
      active = true;
    }
  }

  ekle(Word word) async {
    var val = await WordRepo().add(word);
    showDilog("Kayıt Başarılı");
    update();
    return val;
  }

  updateWord(Word word) async {
    var val = await WordRepo().update(word);
    showDilog("Kayıt Başarılı");
    return val;
  }

  deleteWord(int? id) async {
    var val = await WordRepo().deleteById(id!);
    return val;
  }

  getir() async {
    //here read all data from database
    data.value = await WordRepo().getAll();
    print(data);
    return data;
  }

  translateLanguage(String newValue) async {
    if (newValue == null || newValue.length == 0) {
      return;
    }
    List list = ["I", "i"];
    if (newValue.length == 1 && !list.contains(newValue)) {
      return;
    }

    var translate = await translator.translate(newValue, from: 'en', to: 'tr');

    controllerInput2.text = translate.toString();
    //addNote();
    return translate;
  }

  showDilog(String message) {
    Get.defaultDialog(title: "Bilgi", middleText: message);
  }

  addNote() async {
    var word =
    Word(wordEn: controllerInput1.text, wordTr: controllerInput2.text);
    await ekle(word);
    getir();
    clear();
  }

  clear() {
    controllerInput2.clear();
    controllerInput1.clear();
  }

  updateNote() async {
    var word =
    Word(wordEn: controllerInput1.text, wordTr: controllerInput2.text);
    await updateWord(word);
    await getir();
    update();
  }
}
```

UI:

```
class MainPage extends StatelessWidget {
  bool _active=false.obs();
  String _firstLanguage = "English";
  String _secondLanguage = "Turkish";
  WordController controller = Get.put(WordController());
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    controller.getir();
    return Scaffold(
      drawer: _drawer,
      backgroundColor: Colors.blueAccent,
      appBar: _appbar,
      body: _bodyScaffold,
      floatingActionButton: _floattingActionButton,
    );
  }

  SingleChildScrollView get _bodyScaffold {
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Column(
        children: [
          chooseLanguage,
          translateTextView,
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  AppBar get _appbar {
    return AppBar(
      backgroundColor: Colors.blueAccent,
      centerTitle: true,
      title: Text("TRANSLATE"),
      elevation: 0.0,
    );
  }

  get chooseLanguage => Container(
        height: 55.0,
        decoration: buildBoxDecoration,
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            firstChooseLanguage,
            changeLanguageButton,
            secondChooseLanguage,
          ],
        ),
      );

  get buildBoxDecoration {
    return BoxDecoration(
      color: Colors.white,
      border: Border(
        bottom: BorderSide(
          width: 3.5,
          color: Colors.grey,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  refreshList() {
    controller.getir();
  }

  get changeLanguageButton {
    return Material(
      color: Colors.white,
      child: IconButton(
        icon: Icon(
          Icons.wifi_protected_setup_rounded,
          color: Colors.indigo,
          size: 30.0,
        ),
        onPressed: () {},
      ),
    );
  }

  get secondChooseLanguage {
    return Expanded(
      child: Material(
        color: Colors.white,
        child: InkWell(
          onTap: () {},
          child: Center(
            child: Text(
              this._secondLanguage,
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.blue[600],
                fontSize: 22.0,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  get firstChooseLanguage {
    return Expanded(
      child: Material(
        color: Colors.white,
        child: InkWell(
          onTap: () {},
          child: Center(
            child: Text(
              this._firstLanguage,
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.blue[600],
                fontSize: 22.0,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  get translateTextView => Column(
        children: [
          Card(
            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(8.0)),
            ),
            margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 2.0, right: 2.0, top: 2.0),
            child: _formTextField,
          ),
          Container(
            height: Get.height/1.6,
            child: Obx(() {
              return ListView.builder(
                itemCount: controller.data.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return Card(
                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(5.0)),
                    ),
                    margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 2.0, right: 2.0, top: 0.8),
                    child: Container(
                      color: Colors.white30,
                      height: 70.0,
                      padding:
                          EdgeInsets.only(left: 8.0, top: 8.0, bottom: 8.0),
                      child: Row(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                        children: [
                          Column(
                            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                            children: [
                              firstText(controller.data, index),
                              secondText(controller.data, index),
                            ],
                          ),
                          historyIconbutton,
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  );
                },
              );
            }),
          )
        ],
      );

  get _formTextField {
    return Form(
      key: _formKey,
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          Container(
            color: Colors.white30,
            height: 120.0,
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 16.0, top: 8.0, bottom: 8.0),
            child: Row(

              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: <Widget>[
                textFormFieldEntr,
                favoriIconButton,
              ],
            ),
          ),
          textFormField //burası kapandı
        ],
      ),
    );
  }



  get textFormFieldEntr {
    return Flexible(
      child: Container(
        child: TextFormField(
          onTap: () {
            showMaterialBanner();
          },
          // onChanged: (text) {
          //   controller.translateLanguage(text);
          // },
          controller: controller.controllerInput1,
          maxLines: 6,
          validator: (controllerInput1) {
            if (controllerInput1!.isEmpty) {
              return "lütfen bir değer giriniz";
            } else if (controllerInput1.length > 22) {
              return "en fazla 22 karakter girebilirsiniz";
            }
            return null;
          },
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            hintText: "Enter",
            contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5.0),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void showMaterialBanner() {
    ScaffoldMessenger.of(Get.context!).showMaterialBanner(MaterialBanner(
        backgroundColor: Colors.red,
        content: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 30.0),
          child: Column(
            children: [
              TextFormField(
                controller: controller.controllerInput1,
                maxLines: 6,

                onChanged: (text) {
                  controller.translateLanguage(text);
                  controller.showText();
                },
                validator: (controllerInput2) {
                  if (controllerInput2!.length > 22) {
                    return "en fazla 22 karakter girebilirsiniz";
                  }
                  return null;
                },
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  suffixIcon: IconButton(onPressed: () {
                    FocusScope.of(Get.context!).unfocus();
                    closeBanner();
                  }, icon: Icon(Icons.clear),),
                  contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5.0),
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 80.0),
              TextFormField(
                controller: controller.controllerInput2,
                maxLines: 6,
                validator: (controllerInput2) {
                  if (controllerInput2!.length > 22) {
                    return "en fazla 22 karakter girebilirsiniz";
                  }
                  return null;
                },
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5.0),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        actions: [
          IconButton(
            onPressed: () {


              closeBanner();
            },
            icon: Icon(
              Icons.arrow_forward_outlined,
              color: Colors.indigo,
              size: 36,
            ),
          ),
        ]));
  }

  void closeBanner() {
    ScaffoldMessenger.of(Get.context!).hideCurrentMaterialBanner();
  }


// }  controller.controllerInput1.text==""?_active=false: _active=true;

  get textFormField {
    return Visibility(
      visible: controller.active,
      child: Container(
        color: Colors.white30,
        height: 120.0,
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 16.0, right: 42.0, top: 8.0, bottom: 8.0),
        child: Container(
          child: TextFormField(
            controller: controller.controllerInput2,
            maxLines: 6,
            validator: (controllerInput2) {
              if (controllerInput2!.length > 22) {
                return "en fazla 22 karakter girebilirsiniz";
              }
              return null;
            },
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5.0),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  FutureBuilder<dynamic> get historyWordList {
    return FutureBuilder(
      future: controller.getir(),
      builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot snapShot) {
        if (snapShot.hasData) {
          var wordList = snapShot.data;
          return ListView.builder(
            itemCount: wordList.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return Card(
                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(5.0)),
                ),
                margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 8.0, right: 8.0, top: 0.8),
                child: Container(
                  color: Colors.white30,
                  height: 70.0,
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 8.0, top: 8.0, bottom: 8.0),
                  child: Row(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    children: [
                      Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                        children: [
                          firstText(wordList, index),
                          secondText(wordList, index),
                        ],
                      ),
                      historyIconbutton,
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              );
            },
          );
        } else {
          return Center();
        }
      },
    );
  }

  IconButton get historyIconbutton {
    return IconButton(
      onPressed: () {},
      icon: Icon(Icons.history),
      iconSize: 30.0,
    );
  }

  Text firstText(wordList, int index) {
    return Text(
      "İngilizce: ${wordList[index].wordEn ?? ""}",
      style: TextStyle(
        fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
      ),
      maxLines: 1,
      overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
    );
  }

  Text secondText(wordList, int index) {
    return Text(
      "Türkçe: ${wordList[index].wordTr ?? ""}",
      style: TextStyle(
        fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
      ),
      maxLines: 1,
      overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
    );
  }

  get favoriIconButton {
    return IconButton(
      alignment: Alignment.topRight,
      onPressed: () async {
        bool validatorKontrol = _formKey.currentState!.validate();
        if (validatorKontrol) {
          String val1 = controller.controllerInput1.text;
          String val2 = controller.controllerInput2.text;
          print("$val1 $val2");
          await controller.addNote();
          await refreshList();
        }
        await Obx(() => textFormField(
              controller: controller.controllerInput2,
            ));
        await Obx(() => textFormField(
              controller: controller.controllerInput1,
            ));
      },
      icon: Icon(
        Icons.forward,
        color: Colors.blueGrey,
        size: 36.0,
      ),
    );
  }

  FloatingActionButton get _floattingActionButton {
    return FloatingActionButton(
      onPressed: () {
        Get.to(WordListPage());
      },
      child: Icon(
        Icons.app_registration,
        size: 30,
      ),
    );
  }

  Drawer get _drawer {
    return Drawer(
      child: ListView(
        // Important: Remove any padding from the ListView.
        padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
        children: <Widget>[
          userAccountsDrawerHeader,
          drawerFavorilerim,
          drawersettings,
          drawerContacts,
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  ListTile get drawerContacts {
    return ListTile(
      leading: Icon(Icons.contacts),
      title: Text("Contact Us"),
      onTap: () {
        Get.back();
      },
    );
  }

  ListTile get drawersettings {
    return ListTile(
      leading: Icon(Icons.settings),
      title: Text("Settings"),
      onTap: () {
        Get.back();
      },
    );
  }

  ListTile get drawerFavorilerim {
    return ListTile(
      leading: Icon(
        Icons.star,
        color: Colors.yellow,
      ),
      title: Text("Favorilerim"),
      onTap: () {
        Get.to(FavoriListPage());
      },
    );
  }

  UserAccountsDrawerHeader get userAccountsDrawerHeader {
    return UserAccountsDrawerHeader(
      accountName: Text("UserName"),
      accountEmail: Text("E-mail"),
      currentAccountPicture: CircleAvatar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
        child: Text(
          "",
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 40.0),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simple do it like this

```
class ControllerSample extends GetxController{

 final active = false.obs

 functionPass(){
   active(!active.value);
  }

}
```

on page

```
 final sampleController = Get.put(ControllerSample());

 Obx(
 ()=> Form(
   key: yourkeyState,
   child: Column(
     children: [
       TextFormField(
        //some other needed
        //put the function on onChanged
        onChanged:(value){
              if(value.isEmpty){
                sampleController.functionPass(); 
              }else{
              sampleController.functionPass(); 
         }
             }
        ),
       Visibility(
        visible: sampleController.active.value,
        child: TextFormField(
          //some other info
          )
        ),
     ]
   )
  )
)
```

Comment: Thank you. It is working for me.

Comment: what was my error here?

Comment: your bool empty getter value. in nullsafety its required to used final rather bool but you can also use RxBool inside the controller dont put any variable on Stateless it's quite ugly to look at it better to put all your need on your controller function and variables. Also the way you handle widget is quite confusing to read but all things can be change anyways keep it up nothings wrong to have mistake its an experience to be gain.

Comment: Thank you so much. Your help really worked for me.