# data not rendered in the first time

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-getx

currently i'm trying to implement getx to my app, so far so good, i got the data i wanted but i'm kinda having some trouble when i tried to display the data to the screen.

This is where data supposed to be rendered as a horizontal listview

[Home Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T53k8.png)

But apparently the data will only appear if i click the promo section and click back to the home section on bottom navigation.

[Home Screen 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SIm8f.jpg)

Here is my home_controller.dart

```
class HomeController extends GetxController {
  RxList<Hotels> listHotel = <Hotels>[].obs;
  RxList<Province> listProvince = <Province>[].obs;

  Future getListHotel() async {
    final listHotel = await ApiService.getHotel();
    this.listHotel.value = listHotel;
  }

  Future getListProvince() async {
    final listProvince = await ApiService.getProvince();
    this.listProvince.value = listProvince;
  }

  @override
  void onInit() {
    super.onInit();
    getListHotel();
    getListProvince();
  }
}
```

and this is my home_screen.dart

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final homeController = Get.put(HomeController());
    final authController = Get.put(AuthController());
    final orientation = MediaQuery.of(context).orientation;

    return Scaffold(
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Builder(builder: (context) {
          return Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
            children: [
              SafeArea(
                child: Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                      left: 5.w, right: 5.w, top: 100.h <= 667 ? 5.h : 4.h),
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [
                      Text(
                        "Daftar Hotel",
                        style: TextStyle(
                            color: const Color(0xffF0B900),
                            fontSize: 10.sp,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 31.h,
                        width: orientation == Orientation.landscape
                            ? 100.h
                            : 100.w,
                        child: ListView.separated(
                          shrinkWrap: true,
                          separatorBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                            return SizedBox(
                              width: 1.h,
                            );
                          },
                          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                          itemCount: homeController.listHotel.length,
                          itemBuilder: (context, i) {
                            return InkWell(
                              onTap: () {
                                Navigator.push(
                                    context,
                                    MaterialPageRoute(
                                        builder: (context) => HotelDetailScreen(
                                              id: homeController
                                                  .listHotel[i].id,
                                              checkin: checkInController.text
                                                  .toString(),
                                              checkout: checkOutController.text
                                                  .toString(),
                                            )));
                              },
                              child: SizedBox(
                                  child: Column(
                                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                children: [
                                  SizedBox(
                                    width: 70.w,
                                    height: 20.h,
                                    child: ClipRRect(
                                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                                      child: Image.network(
                                        homeController.listHotel[i].cover,
                                        fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  Padding(
                                    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                        vertical: 8.0),
                                    child: Column(
                                      crossAxisAlignment:
                                          CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                      children: [
                                        Text(
                                          homeController.listHotel[i].name,
                                          style: TextStyle(
                                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                              fontSize: 10.sp),
                                        ),
                                        SizedBox(
                                          width: 70.w,
                                          child: Text(
                                            homeController.listHotel[i].address,
                                            maxLines: 2,
                                            style: TextStyle(
                                                fontWeight: FontWeight.w300,
                                                fontSize: 10.sp),
                                            overflow: TextOverflow.clip,
                                          ),
                                        )
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ],
                              )),
                            );
                          },
                        ),
                      ),
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8.0),
                        child: Text(
                          "Rekomendasi",
                          style: TextStyle(
                              color: const Color(0xffF0B900),
                              fontSize: 10.sp,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                        ),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 25.h,
                        width: orientation == Orientation.landscape
                            ? 100.h
                            : 100.w,
                        child: ListView.builder(
                            scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                            itemCount: homeController.listProvince.length,
                            itemBuilder: (context, i) {
                              String imageUrl = "http://$CURRENT_URL/image/" +
                                  homeController.listProvince[i].cover;
                              return InkWell(
                                onTap: () async {
                                  await launch("https://turu.id/property");
                                },
                                child: Padding(
                                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 8.0),
                                  child: SizedBox(
                                    width: 30.w,
                                    child: Stack(
                                      children: [
                                        SizedBox(
                                          width: 30.w,
                                          height: 25.h,
                                          child: ClipRRect(
                                            borderRadius:
                                                BorderRadius.circular(12),
                                            child: Image.network(
                                              imageUrl,
                                              fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                        Container(
                                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                            borderRadius:
                                                BorderRadius.circular(12),
                                            color:
                                                Colors.black.withOpacity(0.2),
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                        Padding(
                                          padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                                              left: 2.h, bottom: 2.h),
                                          child: Column(
                                            mainAxisAlignment:
                                                MainAxisAlignment.end,
                                            crossAxisAlignment:
                                                CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                            children: [
                                              Text(
                                                homeController
                                                    .listProvince[i].name,
                                                style: TextStyle(
                                                    color: Colors.white,
                                                    fontSize: 10.sp,
                                                    fontWeight:
                                                        FontWeight.bold),
                                              ),
                                            ],
                                          ),
                                        )
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              );
                            }),
                      ),
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8.0),
                        child: Text(
                          "Promo Mantap",
                          style: TextStyle(
                              color: const Color(0xffF0B900),
                              fontSize: 10.sp,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                        ),
                      ),
                      ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          );
        }),
      ),
    );
  }
```

also my index.dart (botnav)

```
class Index extends StatefulWidget {
  const Index({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _IndexState createState() => _IndexState();
}

class _IndexState extends State<Index> {
  int _currentIndex = 0;
  final List<Widget> _container = [
    const HomeScreen(),
    const PromoScreen(),
    const BookingStatusScreen(),
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: _container[_currentIndex],
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
          selectedItemColor: const Color(0xffF0B900),
          unselectedItemColor: const Color(0xffAFAFAF),
          currentIndex: _currentIndex,
          onTap: (index) {
          setState(() {
            _currentIndex = index;
          });
        },
          items: const [
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(
                Icons.home,
              ),
              label: "Beranda",
            ),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(
                Icons.price_change_outlined,
              ),
              label: "Promo",
            ),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(
                Icons.receipt_long_rounded,
              ),
              label: "Transaksi",
            ),
          ])
    );
  }
}
```

Any help will be appreciated, Thank you.

Comment: This could be helpful: [How to Refresh the UI in ListView.Builder using flutter GetX when data is changed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64252344/how-to-refresh-the-ui-in-listview-builder-using-flutter-getx-when-data-is-change)

Comment: You need to wrap your widget with obx widget when you are using .obs type data. Obx(() => child ) like this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69210343/how-to-usage-obx-with-getx-in-flutter  check this link for reference

Comment: i love you both so much!!!